# How to upload a video to Microsoft service using python by sending a "POST" request with application/octet-stream content type

Tags: python, api, azure, video

I want to use Microsoft Azure emotional API to analyse the local video, but how to upload a video to Microsoft service using python by sending a "POST" request with application/octet-stream content type together with the data read from a video file.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far. Other hints on good questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I  post the code at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095252/why-i-cannot-upload-a-video-to-microsoft-azure-api-and-get-the-right-operation-l)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload video to the Azure Storage blob. There is a SDK for python:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage
or you can use pure REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob

For that cases ideally works Valet Key pattern:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/valet-key